# How to access file metadata from database-triggered cloud function in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a project that uses Firebase tools to store images in Firebase Storage and various data in the Realtime Database.

I have a cloud function that is triggered with a Database change. Inside this function I need to access a specific file's metadata to fetch some information (I do not need to modify the metadata).

This is how I access the file.

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
...
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
...
myFile = bucket.file("images/" + imagePath);
```

How do I get the metadata? Naive solutions like these:

```
myFile.metadata;
or
myFile.getMetadata();
```

do not work.
 I assume there should be an easy built-in method and was very surprised to find it extremely hard to find a solution online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#getMetadata) (Client API Reference for the Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client), you should use `getMetadata()`, as follows:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
...
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
...
myFile = bucket.file("images/" + imagePath);

myFile.getMetadata().then(function(data) => {
  const metadata = data[0].metadata;
});
```

Note that it is also possible to call this method as follows:  `myFile.getMetadata(function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {});`.
However, since, in a Cloud Function you must return a Promise when performing asynchronous work (see why [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk)), you should omit the callback and use the Promise that is returned by the method.

Comment: It works, thank you, but please edit your answer to function(data) {... and const metadata = data[0].metadata